# What is the keyboard shortcut in RStudio to quickly insert YAML code from code snippet?

Tags: yaml, rstudio, quarto

I am creating Quarto document in RStudio. I use some YAML settings quite frequently. So, I have added these settings in code snippet in RStudio. What is the keyboard shortcut to quickly insert this code from code snippet to the Quarto document?

The YAML settings are as follows:

```
snippet pdfyaml
  format:
    pdf:
      documentclass: scrbook
      toc: true
      toc-title: "Table of Contents"
      lot: true
      lof: true
      number-sections: true
      fig-cap-location: bottom
      tbl-cap-location: top
      code-line-numbers: true
```

I am open to any other way also, instead of keeping this code in the code snippet, so that I don't have to type this every time I create a new Quarto document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [here](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/productivity/snippets.html) is a great guide for creating snippets. An important thing is that you have to use is `tab`s in your code instead of using spaces. If you don't have that your code snippet isn't valid and won't be recognized. If you simply type the name of your code snippet it will automatically pop up like this:

[image]

Then simply hit enter and it returns your code like this:

```
format:
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrbook
    toc: true
    toc-title: "Table of Contents"
    lot: true
    lof: true
    number-sections: true
    fig-cap-location: bottom
    tbl-cap-location: top
    code-line-numbers: true
```

Comment: Thsnks for mentioning the "most important thing". I was putting 2 spaces instead of pressing tab. Now it is working as expected. I was under the impression that YAML needs 2 spaces instead of tab key.